# JPA/Hibernate join table/join column id's not flagged as foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I define @OneToMany or @ManyToMany relationships, the @JoinColumn's and @JoinTable's work as intended; however, the join columns do not seem to be flagged as foreign keys when I look at my database in SQL Workbench.

For example, if my "User" @Entity has a list of roles:

```
@JoinTable(
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}
)
@ManyToMany
List<Role> roles;
```

The resulting join table works as needed but the columns are only bigint's and are not Foreign Keys.

Among other reasons, I would like the FK's to be flagged as such so I can auto-generate a relationship diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I find a solution after posting the question (and not in the previous 100 google searches)

I had to put this in my Spring application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

The default engine "myISAM" did not support foreign keys apparently.